# Spring Injecting util:map in Kotlin with type safety

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, kotlin, autowired

I have the several bean definitions in XML to store my SQL externally. I want to inject them in Kotlin as `Map<String,String>` however the only way I've been able to make it work so far it injecting it as `Map<Any,Any>`. Is there a way to ensure type safety here. Injecting it as `Map<Any,Any>` feels ghetto.

When I try `Map<String,String>` or even `Map<String,Any>` I get not qualifying beans found...

Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <util:map id="brandSql" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="selectBrands">
            <value type="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    NAME
                FROM BRAND
                ]]>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </util:map>

</beans>
```

Injection into service

```
@Service
open class JdbcBrandService @Autowired constructor(
    private val namedJdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
): BrandService {

    companion object {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcBrandService::class.java)
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "brandSql")
    private lateinit var queries: Map<Any,Any>

    /// methods and what not go here
}
```

In Java I can get away with doing something like the following, but Kotlin's type system being more strict seems to prevent this.

```
@RestController
public class JavaBrandController {

    private final Map<String, String> brandSql;

    @Autowired
    public JavaBrandController(@Qualifier("brandSql") Map sql) {
        this.brandSql = sql;
    }

    @GetMapping("/javaBrands")
    public Map getBrandSql() {
        return this.brandSql;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, it feels strange to have beans floating around that are of such generic types as `Map<String, String>`. It would create confusion when you need other maps.

What I would do is create a container class that holds a reference to the map, so you have a proper type to reference.

Example:

```
class SqlConfig(val map: Map<String, String>)
```

Then create a bean of this type in your xml:

```
<util:map id="brandSql" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <entry key="selectBrands">
        <value type="java.lang.String">
            <![CDATA[
            SELECT
                ID,
                NAME
            FROM BRAND
            ]]>
        </value>
    </entry>
</util:map>

<bean id = "sqlConfig" class = "test.package.SqlConfig">
   <constructor-arg ref = "brandSql"/>
</bean>
```

Now you can autowire it as needed with the proper type in a *non-guetto* way:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "sqlConfig") // <-- the qualifier is no longer needed
private lateinit var queries: SqlConfig
```

Comment: Using Map<String,String> for our SQL along with @Qualifier is more or less standard operating procedure here, but I'm open to better ways to external SQL queries, some of our queries are 500-1000 lines which makes putting them in code not practical. I tried your solution and it is working well! This seems to be one of those places Kotlin and Spring don't quite integrate as well yet, but this way achieves some type safety and avoids doing casts in the code.

Comment: @greyfox if you are looking for an alternative way of storing the queries, I like the solutions in this question and answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140938/reading-sql-file-using-injection-and-utility-reader